# Browser(Chrome)'s timezone is different with server's

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, timezone

I just sent a `new Date()` to browser(Chrome) from server(Node.js), and print the time on server and browser at the same time.

The server give me a localtime which is `Wed Jun 22 2016 22:13:23 GMT+0800 (CST)`, but the browser give me a UST time `016-06-22T14:13:23.283Z`.

I sent data from server to browser with JSON data. How can I fix this difference?

I can convert the timezone manually in browser, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sending the date, how are you doing it? In it's string form?

Consider sending the date as an epoch timestamp (aka [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).

E.g.

```
new Date().getTime()
```

Then on your server you can initialize a new date from the epoch time using `new Date(epochTimestamp)`.

Comment: Thanks. I stored and used the date data as a Date object. So yes in most case it looks like string. I will try the timestamp form.